# Is there any control for achieving truncate the label & show the full text when click the arrow

Tags: xamarin.forms, label, truncated

I have developed the xamarin forms project. I need to truncate the text as default then show the remaining text once the button clicked. Again the text need to be truncated when click the button. It is like "See more" & "See less" functionality. Please anyone suggest me how to achieve this. I have added the screenshot for further reference.

This is how it should look when expanded:

[image]

And this is how it should look like when collapsed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you have the carets wrong. The downward caret is usually the one for an expanded control and vice versa. At the end it's up to you, but you should stick to common UX idioms unless you have a very good reason not to.

If one line of preview text would suffice there is quite an easy solution for your issue: You can set the `LineBreakMode` of the label when your view is clicked:

#### XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test_SO.ExpansibleControl">
    <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" />
    </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid RowSpacing="10" Padding="10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Label Text="{Binding Text}" LineBreakMode="{Binding LineBreakMode}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
          <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CaretCharacter}" HorizontalOptions="End" />
      </Grid>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Just a short outline of what I've done

- Added a `Grid` to `ExpansibleControl`
- Within the grid there is a `Label` for the text

  - The `Text` is bound to the `Text` property of a viewmodel (see below)
  - The `LineBreakMode` is bound to the `LineBreakMode` of a viewmodel
- Furthermore a second `Label` is added for the caret

  - This would be an image in a real app, but for the purpose of demonstration a `Label` will suffice
  - The `Text` is bound to the `CaretCharacter` property of our viewmodel

Furthermore I've added a `TapGestureRecognizer` and bound its `Command` to the `ClickCommand` property of out viewmodel.

#### Viewmodel

As stated above, the views in our `ExpansibleControl` are bound to a viewmodel. Here is the respective code

```
public class ExpansibleControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private char _caretCharacter;
    private bool _isCollapsed;
    private LineBreakMode _lineBreakMode;
    private string _text;

    public ExpansibleControlViewModel()
    {
        ClickCommand = new Command(OnClick);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public char CaretCharacter
    {
        get => _caretCharacter;

        private set
        {
            if (_caretCharacter == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _caretCharacter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Command ClickCommand { get; private set; }

    public bool IsCollapsed
    {
        get => _isCollapsed;

        set
        {
            _isCollapsed = value;

            if (_isCollapsed)
            {
                LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation;
                CaretCharacter = '<';
            }
            else
            {
                LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap;
                CaretCharacter = 'v';
            }
        }
    }

    public LineBreakMode LineBreakMode
    {
        get => _lineBreakMode;
        private set
        {
            if (_lineBreakMode == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _lineBreakMode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _text;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_text == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void OnClick()
    {
        ToggleIsCollapsed();
    }

    private void ToggleIsCollapsed()
    {
        IsCollapsed = !IsCollapsed;
    }
}
```

The viewmodel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` to inform the view that properties have changed (otherwise the bound views would not be updated when a value changes). Due to `CallerMemberNameAttribute` the name of the property that calls `OnPropertyChanged` is automatically passed in the `propertyName` parameter when the optional parameter is omitted.

`IsCollapsed:bool` is rather a helper, to simplify the code and reveal intention. When the callback for `ClickCommand` is called, `IsCollapsed` is inverted. When it has changed, we set the `LineBreakMode` and the `CaretCharacter` to the according values. The setters of those in turn call `OnPropertyChanged` to raise the `PropertyChanged` event and the UI updates. By setting the `LineBreakMode` we *"tell"* the label either to truncate the text or to break text at words (there are other options).

### What if you need a larger portion of text?

There are some options you can go with here.

You could for example fix the `LineBreakMode` to `WordWrap` and set the `HeightRequest` of the `Label` to a value `>0` to show just a portion of the text and to `-1` to show the whole text. In that case you could overlay a gradient from transparent to your background color, to fade out text from top to bottom, as a hint that there is more text to show.

Another option is to manipulate the text itself. You could have a writeable property `OriginalText` and a read-only property `Text` and just truncate the text *"by hand"*.

Anyway, for both options you will have to take care that it scales across platforms, which may or may not be an easy endeavour.

Comment: Thanks for your great response @Paul. But some time the text will come as below two line when the page loaded. At the time i don't need to show the icon. I need to truncate the label when it exceeding two line. I don't need to truncate it when it comes below two line and also don't need to show icon. Please suggest me based on this scenario.

Comment: @MathanKumar: Alright, this is way harder to achieve in a platform-agnostc manner. You might try measuring your string ([see here for example](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67545/how-to-calculate-or-measure-width-of-a-string)), but this will be quite cumbersome.

Comment: It is really helpful one. But I am using listview, every item in a listview which has this label. For platform implementation it seems to be a harder one. Is there any other way like above answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @Paul. It is really helpful one. For various resolution screens like iPad, Tablet, small & large size mobiles it seems to be a harder one. If there is any way it is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With latest Xamarin Forms 3.3 there is a new attribute "MaxLines" for Labels, see https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/maxlines-label-xamarin-forms/ . This should help if you need to display on multiple lines.